# Problema al cargar imagenes estaticas con thymeleaft spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Estoy desarrollando mi pagina web con `spring` y `thymeleaft` y resulta que tengo el siguiente problema, no me cargan las imágenes que tengo metidas en el proyecto (son imágenes estáticas) si no que me sale el típico cuadrado de que no la encuentra.

Mi código **index.html** es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Online Shopping</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css"/>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        /* Make the image fully responsive */
        .carousel-inner img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #columna{
            margin:10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header">...</div>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img th:src="@{'src/main/resources/static/images/roma.jpg'}" src="../static/images/roma.jpg" alt="Roma" width="1100" height="500"/>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img th:src="@{'/images/madrid.jpg'}" src="../static/images/madrid.jpg" alt="Madrid" width="1100" height="500"/>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img th:src="@{'/images/madrid.jpg'}"  src="../static/images/madrid.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <h1 th:text="${categoria.getNombre()}"></h1>

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-carousel">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="owl-item">
                <div class="col-*-2" th:each="prod: ${productos}" id="columna">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="" alt="producto" class="card-img-top"/>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 th:text="${prod.getNombre()}"></h3>
                            <h5>$<span class="text-center" th:text="${prod.getPrecio()}"></span></h5>
                            <p th:text="${prod.getId()}"></p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer">...</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({

    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
}
    )})
</script>

</html>
```

Cabe destacar que en el código he puesto ambas formas de las cuales estoy intentando cargar mi código para ver si alguien da con la solución

Mi estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

Estoy usando **spring version 1.5**

Ya no se que mas probar y yo creo que esta siendo problema de las rutas.

Comment: Con usar `<img th:src="@{/images/madrid.jpg}" />` deberia ser suficiente. De lo contrario podria ser un problema de configuracion que no permite que tu contenido estatico este disponible.

Answer (score 0):

El directorio por defecto para los recursos estáticos en Spring MVC  es 'src/main/resources/static'. 
Deberías crear la carpeta images dentro de static, y quitar el .images del nombre de la carpeta static.

Para consumir esos recursos desde thymeleaf en tu caso sería: `<img th:src="@{images/madrid.jpg}"/>` sin la barra inicial en la ruta

Si no quieres usar la ruta por defecto puedes configurar el resource handler de Spring, aquí explican muy bien cómo: [spring-mvc-static-resources](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources)

Un saludo